# Generate string for using Regular expression on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm making a faker plugin ( [jQuery-Faker](https://github.com/abhinavmsra/jQuery-faker) ) in jQuery which generates fake data for fill in the form corresponding to their field name.
So I want to generate phone number using regular expression `/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/` 
So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at the string from regex family of libraries.

[Here is the one for javascript](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js)

As seen in the **README** you can do

```
var RandExp = require('randexp');
var phoneGenerator = new RandExp(/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/);
phoneGenerator.gen(); // =>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
var n = "01234567890".split("")
, ph = "nnn-nnn-nnnn".replace(/n/g, function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length);
  return n.slice(i, i + 1)[0]
});
document.write(ph);
```